# Trying to make type conversion operator

Tags: c++, class, types

I'm trying to make my operator work (and it sometimes did) but on the output I receive a junk.

I've tried implicit type conversion and in IndProd constructor set private methods of object `f` through setters, nothing helped.

```
class FoodProd : public Exp
{
    private:
        int consump_term;
        char *producer;
    public:
        FoodProd()
        {
            producer = new char[7];
            strcpy(producer, "NONAME");
            consump_term = 0;
        }
        FoodProd(int term, char *str)
        {
            int size1 = strlen(str) + 1;
            producer = new char[size1];
            if (producer)
                strcpy(producer, str);
            consump_term = term;
        }
        FoodProd(const FoodProd &food)
        {
            producer = new char[strlen(food.producer) + 1];
            strcpy(producer, food.producer);
            consump_term = food.consump_term;
        }
        ~FoodProd()
        {
            if (producer)
                delete[] producer;
        }
...
}

class IndProd : public Exp
{
    private:
        char *category;
        int price;
        char *manufacturer;
    public:
        IndProd()
        {
            category = new char[7];
            strcpy(category, "NONAME");
            manufacturer = new char[7];
            strcpy(manufacturer, "NONAME");
            price = 0;
        }
        IndProd(char *cat, int pr, char *manuf)
        {
            category = new char[strlen(cat) + 1];
            strcpy(category, cat);
            price = pr;
            manufacturer = new char[strlen(manuf) + 1];
            strcpy(manufacturer, manuf);
        }
        IndProd(const IndProd &ind)
        {
            category = new char(strlen(ind.category) + 1);
            strcpy(category, ind.category);
            price = ind.price;
            manufacturer = new char(strlen(ind.manufacturer) + 1);
            strcpy(manufacturer, ind.manufacturer);
        }
        ~IndProd()
        {
            if (category)
                delete[] category;
            if (manufacturer)
                delete[] manufacturer;
        }
        IndProd (FoodProd obj)
        {
            category = new char[7];
            strcpy(category, "NONAME");
            manufacturer = new char[strlen(obj.get_producer()) + 1];
            strcpy(manufacturer, obj.get_producer());
            price = 0;
        }
        operator FoodProd const ()
        {
            FoodProd f(0, manufacturer);
            return f;
        }
}
```

`Input:`

```
FoodProd FP(20, "Ukraine");
IndProd ID("BudMat", 1900, "Germany");
FoodProd FP2;
FP2 = ID;
FP2.print();
IndProd ID2;
ID2 = FP;
```

`Output:`

```
Term of consumption: 0 days.
Manufacturer: ↑r;

Category: ♫      Price: 0$
Manufacturer:
```

Comment: Use a `std::string`. Manual memory management should be left to the library or library implementers. At least use `std::unique_ptr` if you want to use dynamic memory. Don't use owning raw pointers.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot my teacher forbids me using string, instead I should use pointers.

Comment: Show a [mcve]. The problem likely lies in the code not shown.

Comment: Can you use `std::unique_ptr`? Your runtime error will most likely become a compile time error.

Comment: Where are your copy-constructors, for the classes, that you are returning, from functions?

Comment: " IndProd (FoodProd obj)" is fishy, you make a copy of something holding pointers...

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot No.

Comment: @Elgernon There is nothing wrong with the code you show. We need more code to help you. You create copies, but we do not know if a proper copy constructor is implemented, or if a destructor exists. For example, if no copy constructor is implemented but the destructor deallocate the memory of the copies, then you will end up with dangling pointers.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé I added it but there's nothing wrong with it because I've been working with it for 3 months.

Comment: There is something wrong with it: You do not provide `operator=`, but you use it. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three.

Comment: Look closely at the brackets in the `new`-expressions in `IndProd`'s non-default constructors.

Comment: On an unrelated note, it's perfectly fine to give `delete` a null pointer, so you never need to check that.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Should I? It is named implicit conversation.

Comment: @molbdnilo Oh, yes, thank you. But, honestly, it did not help.

Comment: `FP2 = ID;` first converts `ID` to `FoodProd` using `operator FoodProd const`. But then this `FoodProd` must be assigned to `FP2`. This uses `operator=`, which you did not implement, so the compiler auto-generated an incorrect one. As soon as the temporary returned by `FoodProd` dies (right at the end of that line), the incorrectly-copied-via-`operator=` object no longer holds valid pointers and `FP2.print();` prints garbage. Please read the Q/A I linked.

Comment: And as @molbdnilo said, `category = new char(strlen(ind.category) + 1);` is incorrect. This dynamically allocates a _single_ character (with the _value_ `strlen(...)+1`) and then treats it as a string, leading to Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Yes, I added `operator=` and it worked! Very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to provide `operator =` for both classes.